# How to prevent user from withdrawing funds twice?

Tags: postgresql, web-applications

I have an endpoint in my api, which lets users specify the amount of money they want to withdraw. Before I send the withdrawal request to the payment processor, I check that the requested amount is <= the user's balance. Once the payment is processed, I deduct the amount from the user's balance.

But I'm thinking, someone could send a second request before the first payment is processed, effectively withdrawing the amount twice. How do I prevent this situation?

PS: I'm using Flask Restless and Postgres, if that makes any difference.

Comment: A transaction can prevents a race condition, but not the user dumbly submitted twice.. I'd recommend also (as in, addition to proper ACID techniques) using a *"transfer nonce"*. Such a nonce can only be used for a *single* transfer and must be validated (eg. it must be verifiable by the server).

Comment: OK, then.  How do you propose that the user might be able to send two transactions?  If it's about the button, disable it when they click on it.

Comment: That's an error-prone solution that I've seen before - and have broken before (on accident and on purpose). Race conditions still apply. It is the *server* that must provide the ultimate validation (which really is the whole reason why it is also important to use transactions at the database level). I propose that the entire process happens with the usage of a server-supplied nonce.

Comment: That prevents the user clicking the button twice?

Comment: No - of course not. That is *additional* client-side checking, of course.

Comment: Sounds like the basis for a decent answer to the question. Answers in comments are not particularly useful... They can't be vetted with votes, and they don't have the usual resources for modding.

Comment: @user2864740: So what happens if the user starts a new nonce?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The old nonce (representing a simultaneous) transfer could be cancelled. Then is the user somehow doesn't complete A before B starts, when they try to complete A they are denied and have to "restart" it.

Comment: @user2864740: What if it has already completed?  See, it's unclear that your description makes the thing bulletproof.  Answer please, with an example.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Then the user has *initiated* the same transfer - from the start - multiple times. There should be several (or at least a begin+confirm) screens/steps in the process, and at that point .. well, I'd just as soon let them. The point is the current transfer cannot be "resubmitted" and any transfer must be completed in it's entirety (meaning that the user is kept aware of the process and current account status) or aborted before another can be done.

Comment: (While I'm generally saying nonce to indicate it is some magic opaque identifier not shared between transfer, it can/should also be associated with the current state of the system - e.g. is only valid for X funds or within Y time or Z recipient.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, where you're co-ordinating with an external service, it's harder than you'd expect.

### Traditional: prepared transactions and XA

The standard solution to this is to use two-phase commit, creating a distributed transaction, where you update the user's record before sending the payment request:

```
UPDATE account 
SET balance = balance - :requested_amount 
WHERE balance >= :requested_amount AND user_id = :userid`
```

If the update succeeds (i.e. they had enough money), you `PREPARE TRANSACTION` to get the DB to confirm the tx will be saved even if the DB crashes. You then send the request off to the provider, and `COMMIT PREPARED` or `ROLLBACK PREPARED` depending on the result.

A lock is held on the balance record by the prepared transaction so no other tx can begin until the prepared tx is rolled back or committed, at which point the new balance is visible.

The old balance shows up to other transactions until the prepared transaction commits or rolls back, unless they use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` or `SELECT ... FOR SHARE`, in which case they'll wait until the prepared TX commits/rolls back. The `NOWAIT` option lets them error out instead. It's all very convenient.

However, this approach scales poorly for very large client counts, and it can become problematic if the payment processor is slow or becomes unresponsive. At least in PostgreSQL there's a limit on how many prepared transactions you can have at a time.

### More scalable: Keep an open-transaction log in the app

If you don't want to use two-phase commit, you'll need to keep an open transaction log instead.

Rather than just checking the users' balance, the app inserts a row into the `active_transactions` table as part of beginning a transaction for the user. If the user already has an active transaction, you'll need a `unique` constraint on `active_transactions.user_id` so if there are concurrent inserts all but one gets rejected.

You'll probably want to update the user's balance in the same transaction.

Other approaches, like `SELECT`ing to check for the user before `insert`ing a record, are unsafe and prone to race conditions. They're OK if they help provide nicer error messages, etc, but are only acceptable as *additional* checks.

Then you send the payment request and wait for a response. Whether it's successful or not, when you get a response you delete the open transaction journal entry and copy it to a history table; if the payment failed, you also put the user's balance back up *in the same transaction*, then commit. Do whatever record-keeping etc you need to in the same transaction you process the payment response in.

### Either way: Transaction cleanup

With prepared transactions or an app-defined transaction journal, now you're left with the problem of what to do when your app/server crashes with transactions active and you don't know what the payment processor response for them was ... or whether you actually sent the request yet.

Most payment processor APIs offer some help for this by letting you attach application-defined tokens to each request. If you were using prepared transactions you'd use the prepared transaction Id for this; if you were doing your own transaction journal you'd use the ID you generated when you inserted the entry into your transaction journal. On restart after a crash/restart you can then check each open transaction in your app and ask the payment processor if it knows about it and if so, whether it was successful or not.

You also have to deal with cases where there was no crash, but a payment processor request *or response* got lost due a transient network issue, etc. You'll need code that periodically checks for apparently abandoned open transactions and re-checks them with the payment processor, like after crash recovery.

There are a number of failure modes you have to deal with:

- App crash / network issue / etc after local payment request saved, but before request sent successfully to processor
- Processor down/unreachable
- Processor sends reply (payment failed / payment OK) but your app is down/unreachable and you never get the response.
- App sends payment request then is restarted before payment processor finishes processing the request (or finishes receiving it). Cleanup code thinks the processor never received the request and discards the local transaction record, then payment processor responds to confirm the payment. (There are a few ways to deal with this, but it's really out of scope for this answer.)
- ... more?

Fun times, eh?

A useful additional sanity check is to periodically (say, daily) fetch the list of transactions from the provider, and compare it to the transactions you thought you did, making sure the completion statuses match. Flag any mismatches for human evaluation. It shouldn't happen, but ....

Comment: I like the second approach (active transactions with constraint on unique user_id) better. As for losing the payment processor response (due to server crash or network issues), running a cron job that clears up active transactions (updating the user balance for successful ones) doesn't seem too bad, or is there something complicated I fail to foresee?

Comment: @tldr The cron job would have to ignore transactions new enough that they might legitimately still be in-progress with the processor, but otherwise that's pretty much what I'd do. You need to have a way to match up your local transaction identifier to the payment processor's identifier though, given that for this to work you *must* commit your local entry *before* you send the request the payment provider so you don't know the provider's transaction ID to store that in your transactions table.

Comment: @tldr ... which is why I suggest including your local transaction Id in the identifier you send to the provider.

Comment: yep, I'll insert transaction into the active_transaction table, and pass its id to the processors api. Also, I'm planning to run the cron job every 5 minutes or so, this should be enough time for the legitimate transactions to have been cleared out.

Comment: @tldr If you run it every 5 mins and *only look for transactions already older than 5 minutes*, yes. Otherwise some unfortunate transaction that just started when the cron job ran might get cleaned up.

Comment: Haha, yes! That's what I meant to say. Need to work on those communication skills. Thanks again!